# Help Solving Equation

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to solve this equation for a few hours, but somehow I'm stuck somewhere and I could use some help.

$\frac{1} {x^2} = -\frac {2(x-a)} {a^3} + \frac {1} {a^2}$

I know from the book that there are two solutions (this is the equation of a tangent line to $x^2$). One solution is $x = a$:

$\frac{1} {x^2} - \frac {1} {a^2} = -\frac {2(x-a)} {a^3}$

The second solution is $x = - \frac {a} {2}$, but I don't know how to get to it.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $x^2a^3$ should help.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Note that a has two different coefficients in the denominator on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lcm$(x^2,a^3,a^2)=x^2a^3$ multiplying either sides by that and rearranging we get

$$a^3-ax^2+2x^2(x-a)=0$$

$$2x^2(x-a)-a(x^2-a^2)=0$$

$$(x-a)\{2x^2-a(x+a)\}=0$$

If $\displaystyle x-a\ne0,2x^2-ax-a^2=0$

Now, $\displaystyle2x^2-ax-a^2=2x^2-2ax+ax-a^2=2x(x-a)+a(x-a)=(x-a)(2x+a)$

But we have already assumed $x-a\ne0$

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I'm not used to this kind of simplifications. the lcm technique was new to me for example. Hope I can find similar exercises to practice somewhere.

Comment: @Oscar, have you understood the method. You can try https://archive.org/details/higheralgebra032813mbp and https://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall

Comment: I have understood the method but since it's new to me I need to practice. Thanks a lot for the links.